# Where can I find AppFabric Licensing info?

Tags: licensing, appfabric

Can anyone point me to the AppFabric licensing info?

Comment: Which flavour of AppFabric - Azure or Windows Server?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows Server AppFabric is free, so there's no licensing 'cost' involved - it's treated as an add-on to Windows/the .NET framework. The Azure AppFabric SDK *does* come with a license which states what you can redistribute, but the licence screen in the Windows Server AppFabric installer refers you to the Windows licence.

[alt text http://philippursglove.com/stackoverflow/appfabricinstallerlicencescreen.png](http://philippursglove.com/stackoverflow/appfabricinstallerlicencescreen.png)

However, while AppFabric has no cost implications in and of itself, if you want to use the high availability features in an AppFabric cache, all cache hosts must be running Windows Server Enterprise Edition. There are more details on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790974.aspx) (para. 3), this also refers you to the [installation guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=40&p=3&SrcDisplayLang=en&SrcCategoryId=&SrcFamilyId=467e5aa5-c25b-4c80-a6d2-9f8fb0f337d2&u=http%3a%2f%2fgo.microsoft.com%2ffwlink%2f%3fLinkID%3d184618) (although having just read through the installation guide again I couldn't see this restriction mentioned anywhere).

Comment: Thanks for the info Phil.  However, I read somewhere that some of the components of Windows Server AppFabric require Server Enterprise Edition.  Do you know where I can find that info?